# Change HTML Page in Crossrider Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, crossrider

I have a popup called **picker.html** that contains two options - either going to the options page (that crossrider doesnt natively support) or opening up a webpage. There could also be more options.

Now, when the "Go to Options" button is pressed i want to change the popup to go to the file **options.html**.

I tried using `appAPI.browserAction.setPopup` but it only work after another click on the browser action making it useless. `window.location` also doesnt work as crossrider always uses `background.html` and there's no API to just get the path of a resource file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `document.open` and `appAPI.resources.get` to change the whole HTML. Then you need to run `crossriderMain` to make sure all used resources are being loaded.

See the working example below. From my experience it's not possible to change the height of the new popup / page, please edit this answer if someone finds a tested possibility (CSS doesn't appear to be working here).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function crossriderMain($) {
                appAPI.resources.includeCSS('html/bootstrap.min.css');
                appAPI.resources.includeCSS('html/skin.css');

                appAPI.resources.includeJS('js/bootstrap.min.js');
            }

            appAPI.ready(function($) {
                $("#gooptions").click(function() {
                    var newDoc = document.open("text/html", "replace");
                    newDoc.write(appAPI.resources.get('options.html'));
                    newDoc.close();

                    $("body").css("width","400px");
                    crossriderMain($);

                    eval(appAPI.resources.get('js/bootstrap.min.js')); 
                    //Use eval with any JS you need to load for the new page, it won't be loaded from crossriderMain($)!
                });
                $("#goproton").click(function() {
                    appAPI.openURL({url: "https://protonmail.ch/login", where:"tab", focus:true});
                    window.close();
                });
            }); 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="well bs-component" style="margin:0; border-radius:0; border:none; padding:5px;">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
              <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin-bottom:5px; padding:0;">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="gooptions" style="width:100%;">Go to Options</button>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-12" style="padding:0;">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="goproton" style="width:100%;">Open ProtonMail</button>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```